# sbt.ResolveException on compilation in IDEA

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Everything works fine when I run "play clean compile" directly from comsole.

But if I'm clicking "Make Project" from IDEA I get:

```
Play 2 compiler
:  (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.6!slf4j-api.jar
 Total time: 6 s, completed 23-Apr-2013 17:59:14
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem this week. Solved removing the `~/.ivy2` directory.

#### Update:

try the following,
Remove this files:

- `/path/to/your/play/home/repository/cache/org.slf4j`
- `/path/to/your/play/home/repository/local/org.slf4j`
- `/path/to/your/play/home/repository/.sbt.ivy.lock`

Comment: Was the directory situated in your user directory? I've found one there and after deletion problem still persists.

Comment: This worked for me (removing the `cache/org.slf4j` etcetera files). Why does it work?

Answer (score 1):

For me this started when I updated my application to use Play 2.1.3 instead of 2.1.0 in `plugins.sbt` ... but forgot to actually download the 2.1.3 release and add it to my path.